# Why is my perl replace not working?

Tags: html, regex, perl, shell, replace

I have the following perl search and replace :

With Escapes :

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/ onclick=\"img=document.getElementById(\'img_1\')\; img.style.display = (img.style.display == \'none\' ? \'block\' : \'none\');return false"//' test.html
```

Without Escapes :

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/ onclick="img=document.getElementById('img_1'); img.style.display = (img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');return false"//' test.html
```

My objective is to replace `onclick="img=document.getElementById('img_1'); img.style.display = (img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');return false"` with nothing in the file `test.html`. What am I messing up?

I keep on getting the error : `-sh: syntax error near unexpected token`)'` which I cannot help but feel is because of some stupid escaping on my part. Please help me out.

Comment: `perl -pi -w -e 's/ onclick=\"img=document.getElementById(q{img_1}); img.style.display = (img.style.display == \'none\' ? \'block\' : \'none\');return false"//' test.html`   ????? Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ You didn't specify for which shell you are building the command. I'm going to assume `sh` or `bash`. ]

---

### Problem #1: Converting text into a regex pattern

Many characters have a special meaning in regex patterns. Among those you used, `(`, `)`, `.` and `?` are special. These need to be escaped.

If you want to match

```
onclick="img=document.getElementById('img_1'); img.style.display = (img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');return false"
```

You need to use the pattern

```
onclick="img=document\.getElementById\('img_1'\); img\.style\.display = \(img\.style\.display == 'none' \? 'block' : 'none'\);return false"
```

So your Perl code is

```
s/onclick="img=document\.getElementById\('img_1'\); img\.style\.display = \(img\.style\.display == 'none' \? 'block' : 'none'\);return false"//
```

---

### Problem #2: Converting text (a Perl program) into a shell literal

This is the problem you asked about.

Sections quoted by single quotes ("`'`") end at the next single quote (unconditionally), so the following is wrong:

```
echo 'foo\'bar'   # Third "'" isn't matched.
```

If you wanted to output "`foo'bar`", you could use

```
echo 'foo'\''bar'   # Concatenation of "foo", "'" and "bar".
```

`foo` and `bar` are quoted by single quotes, and the single quote is escaped using `\`. `\` works here because it's outside of single quotes.

So, the lesson is basically use `'\''` instead of `'` inside single quotes.

you want to pass the following program to Perl:

```
s/onclick="img=document\.getElementById\('img_1'\); img\.style\.display = \(img\.style\.display == 'none' \? 'block' : 'none'\);return false"//
```

To do so, you'll need to create a shell literal that produces the correct argument, meaning we want to surround the whole with single quotes and escape the existing single quotes. We get the following:

```
's/onclick="img=document\.getElementById\('\''img_1'\''\); img\.style\.display = \(img\.style\.display == '\''none'\'' \? '\''block'\'' : '\''none'\''\);return false"//'
```

As such, the entire command would be

```
perl -i -wpe's/onclick="img=document\.getElementById\('\''img_1'\''\); img\.style\.display = \(img\.style\.display == '\''none'\'' \? '\''block'\'' : '\''none'\''\);return false"//' test.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the next:

```
perl -lnE 'say quotemeta $_'
```

and feed it with your plain input:

```
onclick="img=document.getElementById('img_1'); img.style.display = (img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');return false"
```

you will get:

```
onclick\=\"img\=document\.getElementById\(\'img_1\'\)\;\ img\.style\.display\ \=\ \(img\.style\.display\ \=\=\ \'none\'\ \?\ \'block\'\ \:\ \'none\'\)\;return\ false\"
```

So using it:

```
perl -i -pe "s/onclick\=\"img\=document\.getElementById\(\'img_1\'\)\;\ img\.style\.display\ \=\ \(img\.style\.display\ \=\=\ \'none\'\ \?\ \'block\'\ \:\ \'none\'\)\;return\ false\"//"
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Some things are easier when you don't use a one-liner.  Less things to escape, and not as fragile.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $literal_string = q{ onclick="img=document.getElementById('img_1'); img.style.display = (img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');return false"};

while (<>) {
    s/\Q$literal_string//;
    print;
}
```

Then execute the script:

```
perl -i thescript.pl test.html
```